# How to use the rule validation in FormRequest class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Company, where I like to validate the update request. Until now I validated the request inside the `update()` action but I like to move this to its own `CompanyUpdateRequest`.

In the validation I check of the uniqueness of the tax number but of course I like to allow the same tax number for the very company.

```
'tax_number' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($company->tax_number),
],
```

This works as long it is placed inside the action, where I have `$company` already:

```
public function update(Request $request, Company $company) 
{
}
```

My question is now, how I get the company inside the `CompanyUpdateRequest`?

I know that I could put the ID of the company inside a hidden field in the form, send it along with the request, pull the company from DB ... but this feels kind of wrong. Does anybody have a better / another approach or idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show your route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `route()` method. Assume your route parameter name is `company`-

```
$this->route('company');
```

> Note: `parameter` method inside route method needs to exactly same as `url route` parameter. In this case-
>
> `Route::post('yourUrl/{company}','SomeController@method');`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any data through a form:

```
<input name="company_id" value="{{ $company->tax_number }}" type="hidden">
```

Then in the `CompanyUpdateRequest` class:

```
Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($request->company_id),
```

You can also change this rule to:

```
'companies' => 'unique:companies,company_id,' . $request->company_id,
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can get it with `$this->route('paramName');`

```
Rule::unique('companies')->ignore($this->route('company')),
```

Comment: That's the same solution as in @Sohel0415 answer.